# Do the $p$-norms in $\mathbb R^2$ have a nice geometric intuition behind them?

Tags: geometry, intuition, normed-spaces

For $p\geq 1,$ the $p$-norm of a vector $(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2$ is the number $\|(x,y)\|_p=(|x|^p+|y|^p)^{1/p}.$

I learned this definition some time ago, but I never really understood it. Is there a useful and not too difficult to understand geometric intuition that explains it (at least for natural $p$)?

Comment: Draw a picture of $||x||_p = 1$.

Comment: @Thomas I know what the unit circles look like, more or less. I've used Wolphram Alpha to draw the pictures. But I'm not sure how it explains what the norms actually mean.

Comment: I know that for $p=1$ we can think of it as a distance we have to walk to get somewere in a city with orthogonal streets. And of course I have a pretty good intuition of the $p=2$ case.

Comment: @Bartek, right, that's why the $1$-norm is sometimes called the "Manhattan norm", since the city of Manhattan is divided into blocks... for the $\infty$-norm, see [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_distance).

Comment: @J.M. Oh, cool! Does the knight also have its normed space?

Comment: Bartek: No since the points (0,0) and (2,0) are at knight-distance 2 but the points (0,0) and (1,0) are at distance 3 (instead of 1). Hence the knight-distance is not a norm distance.

Comment: I recently found a nice article, about [$π_p$, the value of $π$ in $ℓ_p$](http://math.stanford.edu/~vakil/files/07-0333.pdf)